# reCAPTCHA - SSL certificate verify failed error with Devise and Recaptcha gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement reCAPTCHAwith [recaptcha gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) and tutorial as seen on [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise) but when the captcha passes and `create` method gets called it gives an error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I've had same error with omniauth-facebook but solved it by adding `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = 'C:\cacert.pem'` to my environment but no luck with reCAPTCHA. I also tried `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` and it still gives the same error.

I've tried deploying to ELB and it still doesn't work.

### Update

It started working on AWS ELB somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your ruby version can't find the CA Root Certificates, if you used RVM to install your Ruby you might be in luck by doing this:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

However, if you need to manually do this, this is how I would do it:

- Download Root certificates from (only .pem - Googles certificates are signed by GeoTrust)
  https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/
- Find your rubygems path ('gem which rubygems')
- Copy into your ssl_certs the .pem files, this should be enough

Please try it out and let us know.

Comment: I've already downloaded .pem file from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and set the env variable to it which seems includes GeoTrust certificates.

Comment: I see if it's still not working it might be not the right certificate, each CA authority has its own root certificates, download the GeoTrust, put them there and try again

Comment: I've tried putting them all in my .pem file but the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you try restarting the Rails server?

Comment: Of course I did restart the rails server. What is weird is that it's not working even on AWS. Another auths like Facebook worked smoothly without any extra configure on AWS before.

Comment: This worked for me. I also rebuilt all the gems once I updated all my certs.

Answer (score 0):

I added `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` line at the end of **class Application** on `config/application.rb` and it worked with recaptcha verification.

Comment: And what does this do? Seems to me like you are telling the app to ignore SSL verification.

Comment: Actually I was trying to workaround for development env, so mention solution worked for me without verifying SSL.